# Problem with dynamic public IP address ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, cloud, load-balancing

I want to run my application on EKS. Currently all the pods are running and I can access website, when I set A record in GoDaddy to point to public IP address for Elastic Network Interface, that is associated with the Elastic Load Balancer. Problem is that public IP dynamically changes. When I access DNS name for the Load Balancer provided by aws, I get nginx 404 not found error. When I set CNAME record pointing to that DNS name, I get the same result. How can I handle the changing IP and DNS name not to return 404 error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can go for [AWS Global Accelerator](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/)

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for some free possibilities, if there are some.